# MySQL Full-text search and SOUNDEX

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, soundex

I am trying to implement a first and last name search using full-text search and SOUNDEX (in case if the name is misspelled).

I was trying to do something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM employees 
WHERE 
    MATCH SOUNDEX(first_name, last_name) AGAINST SOUNDEX('John 1969 Ivan')
```

but this is not a valid syntax.

What I want to achieve, is that when a user types for example "Jon Ivan", the columns

```
first_name | last_name
----------------------
  John        Ivan
```

would match.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure whether this can be combined with MATCH...AGAINST, but maybe full text search can tackle it alone? It has *some* tolerance for spelling differences

Comment: Related: [Whats the easiest site search application to implement, that supports fuzzy searching?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1899470)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL tends to fall short when it comes to text searches, fuzzy searches, misspellings, etc. I highly recommend an indexing solution like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).  Solr supports four different types of phonetic searches: Soundex, RefinedSoundex, Metaphone, and DoubleMetaphone.  It has geospatial searching and misspelling searches along with butterfly/butterflies searching. I think you will REALLY be happy with the results you get. It is lightening fast compared to MySQL